# Tab menus' content include another tab menus

Tags: css

I am trying to build a page with css `:target` attribute

topbar => horizontal tab menus

tab => vertical tab menus

But I stuck on this problem

How to build a nested tab page with only css?

Or there's no way for me to implement this without javascript?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j1ouz4z/1/)

Comment: Have you looked at Twitter Bootstrap, might do something like this? I always use this as a base for templating.

Comment: try bootstrap you will learn html and css very fast :)

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362982/struggling-to-create-mobile-version-of-my-navigation/33363414#33363414

Comment: Use this fiddle to solve your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/7fshu82L/3/